# Controller's variables aren't working with form placed inside partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have - probably stupid - problem with render my form.
I have two controllers: ContentController - responsible for content views of tabbed page and ParticipantsController scaffold generated for handling database model.
I want to make a form for sign in new participants and put it in partial _new.html.erb which then will be embedded in "schedule" view of my ContentController. 
I'm really new to rails, so maybe I missed something out but when i put form like this:

```
<%= form_for @participant do |f| %> 
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    ...
```

I got an error:

```
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

In my controller I have:

```
def new
    @participant = Participant.new
end
```

So I guess everything should be alright.

When I use Participant.new instead of @participant in my form, everything is rendering correct; but im not sure if that will be working with database, I mean I want the new participant record to be created in db after clicking submit button.

I hope I pass enough info for You guys to help me out.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you that you can't have the following:

```
<%= form_for nil do |f| %>
<%= form_for [] do |f| %>
```

My guess here is that your @participant is set to nil and that it doesn't come from your Participantst#new action.

it would simply work if you do this:

```
<%= form_for Participant.new do |f| %>
```

Though it is not recommended.

You need to check that the view containing your form is actually rendered by the new action of your ParticipantsController.
For more info see https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2451

Comment: Ok, so if I leave it with Participant.new it will be cooperating with db and stuff, correct ?

Comment: Hmm... now I'm pretty sure that my partials don't see any variables from controller, how to fix this ?

Comment: Try to pass locals with your partial like this                                                                     <%= render :partial => 'form', :locals => { :participant => @participant } %>

Comment: Ehh... I thought I'll manage since this advice about locals, but it is still not working and i don't know what i did wrong. Maybe problem is that i want to render partial with vars from other controller than the parent controller of view from within i try to render the partial